# how to avoid Getting whitespace due to removing the appbar and statusbar in android using flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, toolbar, statusbar, appbar

I am new to flutter, i am creating a screen without appbar and status bar, when i run the code its showing a white space in the bottom. If i try to use screenheight to divide it into two then am getting the ovrflowing of my second container.

But the code is running fine in iPhone screen,

Note: i have removed the appbar from the scaffold and removed the notification bar in my main.dart

```
return Scaffold(
      // appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Screen Height')),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(color: Colors.red),
            )
          ],
        ));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

to get full screen app, in your `main` method:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: I added SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]); already in the main.dart, for that only i am getting the full screen but the issue is the white area in the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @LoVe's answer, you might also want to add `extendBody:true` and `extendBodyBehindAppBar: true` to your scaffold.

Comment: According to Flutter docs, these two fields only take effects when the `Scaffold` have a `bottomNavigationBar` and an `appBar` respectively, otherwise they change nothing

Comment: Ah - yes. Sorry I missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to replicate the issue you mentioned. Below is the simplest code that I tried using your code on Android emulator and don't see the white space at the bottom:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: MyHomePage()
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold( // appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Screen Height')),
        body: Column(children:
        [
          Expanded
            (child: Container
            (color: Colors.white),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(color: Colors.red),
          )
        ],
        )
    );
    // );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Darshan, please add this in your main.dart SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);  and rebuild the app, you will get the white space in the bottom.

Comment: I don't think this must be posted as an answer but rather as a comment

Comment: @LoVe you can't put an entire sample code as a comment. Moreover, by sharing entire code, the OP may cross-check what they may have missed that may help them to fix the issue. Hence that was put as an answer.

Comment: @Darshan I understand, but my point was that your answer, well, didn't answer his question about removing the white space, that is just what I meant :)

Comment: @Darshan can you share your screenshot? note: there will not be the statusbar/notification bar if you are using SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]).

Answer (score 0):

There should be an extra line in styles.xml too ,to make this working on Android at least.

```
 1. Add SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
 2. Add <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item> in styles.xml
```

i found a solution here:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46486