# How can i remove blank space under the bottom app bar?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```
class HomeView extends GetView<HomeController> {
  @override
  final HomeController controller = Get.put(HomeController());

  buildNavBar() {
    return Obx(
      () => BottomAppBar(
        shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        color: MyColorStyle.primary,
        notchMargin: 4,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          iconSize: 30.0,
          showSelectedLabels: false,
          showUnselectedLabels: false,
          selectedItemColor: MyColorStyle.primary,
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey[600],
          onTap: controller.changeTabIndex,
          currentIndex: controller.tabIndex.value,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          items: const [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.dashboard), label: ''),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today), label: ''),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.show_chart), label: ''),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.settings), label: ''),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      extendBody: true,
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: MyColorStyle.primary,
        elevation: 2,
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet(
            isScrollControlled: true,
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) => ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(40), topRight: Radius.circular(40)),
              child: SizedBox(
                height: Get.height * 0.8,
                child: Container(),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: buildNavBar(),
      body: Obx(
        () => IndexedStack(
          index: controller.tabIndex.value,
          children: [
            SizedBox(),
            SizedBox(),
            SizedBox(),
            SizedBox(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image here(blue space)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaIcv.jpg)

I tried solving it with SafeArea. I can't remove the space at the bottom. None of the methods have achieved the solution I wanted.

When I made a BottomNavBar like this a while ago, there was no auto-space for the home indicator. For this, I couldn't reach a property in Scaffold or anywhere else.

Comment: `extendBodyBehindAppBar:true` from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61427189/how-to-avoid-getting-whitespace-due-to-removing-the-appbar-and-statusbar-in-andr

Comment: There was no change.

Answer (score 0):

That is the gesture system navigation bar, which depends on the user's phone settings. You cannot remove but you can change the color. In the main method, before calling runApp(),

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      systemNavigationBarColor: appWhite,
      systemNavigationBarDividerColor: appWhite,
      systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark));
  runApp(const App());
}
```

Comment: I have no problem with home indicator or something. I have not encountered such a situation in my other applications. I want to remove the blue area under the NavBar. The blue color is my app's primary color by the way.

Comment: that is gesture navigation. home button and back button and recent app are default navigation. So the (blue) bar will be there. That's why I said to change the color if you feel the bar color is weird.

Comment: the bar will be present in all apps. irrespective of the frameworks for development. Flutter by default applies the app's primary color, in your case it's blue. So you can change the systemNavigationBarColor to white and systemNavigationBarDividerColor to grey or your primary blue

Comment: Thank you for the information you mentioned. As far as I understand, this space is created automatically when we use the BottomAppBar. This time, when I change these settings, it is not white, it stills blue.

Comment: it is not only for the bottom app bar but for the entire app. Still you are having blue even after applying the above code? Can you update the code and error in question?

Comment: The blue space I'm talking about only occurs on the page where I use the BottomAppBar. There is no such situation in other pages of my application. I managed to make the space white by wrapping my page with SafeArea and container and giving it color.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't remove the space at the bottom, but I wrapped my Scaffold with SafeArea. I made the color of the space the same as my page by wrapping the SafeArea in the Container and giving the Container a white color. Sayfamın başlangıcı bu şekilde oldu.

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
color: Colors.white,
child: SafeArea(
child: Scaffold(

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).